# Whatsapi throwing 500 server error only on remote server

Tags: php, internal-server-error, whatsapi

My code is

```
include "src\whatsprot.class.php"; 
$username = "91xxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Mobile Phone prefixed with country code so for india it will be 91xxxxxxxx 
$password = "password";
$identity = strtolower(urlencode(sha1($username, true)));
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $identity, "WhatsApp Messaging", true);
```

But This part of the code

```
$w = new WhatsProt($username, $identity, "WhatsApp Messaging", true);
```

is giving me the following error only on remote server

"The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.domain.com/WAPP/Chat-API-master/code.php It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly. "

This code runs perfectly on my local machine.

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Happened for me due to Cloudflare outage. We use a whatsapp business solution called Wati and apparently they use it internally and our remote server is hosted in an aws region that seems to have suffered the outage. Which wasn't the case for my local IP.